# Ubuntu config with multiple network adapter interface, vlans running on VM Workstation Pro 12 to run AVAHI service / app

Tags: 15.10, vmware-workstation, avahi

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated

Objective 
-Use Ubuntu along with the AVAHI app / service to relay multicast across my 6 vLan networks to allow devices within each of these separate vLans to see apple airprint airplay etc
-My underlying network, switches, and routing are config and should support

Problem 
-network traffic .. (primarily pings)  to the separate network adapters within Ubuntu with exception of the untagged Network interface do not respond .. the pings times out .. if I enable only one of the adapters within ubuntu it works correctly .. so this proves the networking and routing ok good  .. 
-problem seems when all the network adapters are active concurrently even if only 2 .. the ping response (from entirely different PC on network) and routing from all but 1 of the adapters just times out .. also worth noting that if I ping a disabled adapter I get a different message from my router that the destination host unreachable and this message is returned from the gateway IP of the sending PC of the ping .. just also indirectly seems to confirm the original ping that just times out when the adapters is active does arrive but is just not returned properly
-the AVAHI script does not work .. which is not a surprise given the behavior above

Background and Setup
-Hardware is Dell Optiplex Windows W7 x64 fully updated latest OS 
-VM Workstation Pro 12 .. new install running with trial license
-Added Umbuntu v 15.10 VM .. 
-My network and switches have vLans … and I have high-end firewall appliance where I manage routing and rules with full vlan support
-On the Dell PC W7 I have added 6 separate nic adapters (intel v19.5 proset drivers with vlan support) with each mapped to separate vLan network 
-From separate PC I get a ping response to each of the W7 individual network adapters .. VM attaches in bridge to these NICs
-VM Workstation is setup to bridge each of these network adapters into the VM enviro
-ubuntu then is configured to use each adapter .. this is confirmed with IP config

What I think is the problem
-routing within ubuntu does not understand how to respond to individual adapters .. possibly
-possibly something in the bridge within VM loses the vLan tag .. which then prevents Ubuntu from responding correctly

Things I have tried 
-turning on IP forwarding, insured that IPtables was not blocking the communication and adding the interfaces to /etc/network/interfaces. Which to no avail it still does not work.
-added routing statements with the route add command and we still cannot ping that interface.

### -checked the firewall within the Ubuntu and no rules that would prevent communication

Research & relevant links
https://kindlund.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/configuring-multiple-default-routes-in-linux/
http://brainscraps.wikia.com/wiki/Setup_Gateway_Routing_On_Multiple_Network_Interfaces
ubuntuforums.org showthread 2117430